# What is the best way to declare global variables in Vue.js?

Tags: global-variables, vue.js

I need access to my `hostname` variable in every component.

Is it a good idea to put it inside `data`?

Am I right in understanding that if I do so, I will able to call it everywhere with `this.hostname`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Warning:** The following answer is using Vue 1.x. The `twoWay` data mutation is removed from Vue 2.x (fortunately!).

In case of "global" variables—that are attached to the global object, which is the window object in web browsers—the most reliable way to declare the variable is to set it on the global object explicitly:

```
window.hostname = 'foo';
```

However form Vue's hierarchy perspective (the root view Model and nested components) the data can be passed downwards (and can be mutated upwards if twoWay binding is specified).

For instance if the root viewModel has a `hostname` data, the value can be bound to a nested component with  [`v-bind`](http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) directive as `v-bind:hostname="hostname"` or in short `:hostname="hostname"`.

And within the component the bound value can be accessed through component's `props` property.

Eventually the data will be proxied to `this.hostname` and can be used inside the current Vue instance if needed.

```js
var theGrandChild = Vue.extend({
  template: '<h3>The nested component has also a "{{foo}}" and a "{{bar}}"</h3>',
    props: ['foo', 'bar']
});

var theChild = Vue.extend({
  template: '<h2>My awesome component has a "{{foo}}"</h2> \
             <the-grandchild :foo="foo" :bar="bar"></the-grandchild>',
  props: ['foo'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      bar: 'bar'
    };
  },
  components: {
    'the-grandchild': theGrandChild
  }
});


// the root view model
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    foo: 'foo'
  },
  components: {
    'the-child': theChild
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<h1>The root view model has a "{{foo}}"</h1>
<the-child :foo="foo"></the-child>
```

---

In cases that we need to mutate the parent's data upwards, we can add a `.sync` modifier to our binding declaration like `:foo.sync="foo"` and specify that the given 'props' is supposed to be a `twoWay` bound data.

Hence by mutating the data in a component, the parent's data would be changed respectively.

For instance:

```js
var theGrandChild = Vue.extend({
  template: '<h3>The nested component has also a "{{foo}}" and a "{{bar}}"</h3> \
             <input v-model="foo" type="text">',
    props: {
      'foo': {
        twoWay: true
      },  
      'bar': {}
    }
});

var theChild = Vue.extend({
  template: '<h2>My awesome component has a "{{foo}}"</h2> \
             <the-grandchild :foo.sync="foo" :bar="bar"></the-grandchild>',
  props: {
    'foo': {
      twoWay: true
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return { bar: 'bar' };
  },  
  components: {
    'the-grandchild': theGrandChild
  }
});

// the root view model
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    foo: 'foo'
  },
  components: {
    'the-child': theChild
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<h1>The root view model has a "{{foo}}"</h1>
<the-child :foo.sync="foo"></the-child>
```

Comment: Define "soon", please.

Comment: I guess he meant "never".

Comment: He doesn't need to. Vue was faster and reimplemented it: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier

Answer (score 97):

As you need access to your hostname variable in every component, and to change it to localhost while in development mode, or to production hostname when in production mode, you can define this variable in the prototype.

Like this:

```
Vue.prototype.$hostname = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

And $hostname will be available in all Vue instances:

```
new Vue({
  beforeCreate: function () {
    console.log(this.$hostname)
  }
})
```

In my case, to automatically change from development to production, I've defined the $hostname prototype according to a Vue production tip variable in the file where I instantiated the Vue.

Like this:

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$hostname = (Vue.config.productionTip) ? 'https://hostname' : 'http://localhost:3000'
```

An example can be found in the docs:
[Documentation on Adding Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Simple-Example)

More about production tip config can be found here:

[Vue documentation for production tip](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#productionTip)

Comment: For clarity, the first line goes in main.js

Comment: In my opinion this is a great alternative to using vuex if you want to create your own ES6 data model to replace the global "store" in vuex. This gives you complete flexibility with your code structure. Example: Vue.prototype.$session = new Session(), where "Session" is a custom ES6 class. This allows you to create a globally accessible session object but with your own data structure.

Comment: You should prefer `Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$hostname', { value: 'http://localhost:3000' }` since the variable would be _read-only_ by default. You can see more details in this article: https://dzone.com/articles/use-any-javascript-library-with-vuejs

Comment: May i ask why `$hostname` over `hostname`? Is it just a style convention for custom properties, or avoiding collisions for property names..?

Comment: @DigitalNinja from the docs: "No magic is happening here. $ is a convention Vue uses for properties that are available to all instances. This avoids conflicts with any defined data, computed properties, or methods."  [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#The-Importance-of-Scoping-Instance-Properties)

Comment: @DigitalNinja, so this is a convention to not have unexpected conflicts

Comment: Note: It is also available in Vue Router. Ex. `Vue.prototype.my_routes = {}; /* Will be available in router like this -> */ new VueRouter({ routes: this.app.my_routes })`

Comment: You are awesome, thanks man.
I have one more question. Can i use this variable inside <template> ?

Comment: You are welcome! Yes you can use in the same way as if you had declared in `data()`  Thanks for the compliment, and any doubts I'here :)

Comment: Is there any way to make these global variables persist when navigating between routes?

Comment: @NickeManarin have you tried it? here works between routes by Vue Router

Comment: @JosielFaleiros Perhaps it's not working because my routes are lazy loaded (separated JS files).

Comment: The property is defined in the imported Vue, so check if you are using the same Vue imported, because reimporting could lead the property to not working, (not sure about this)

Comment: Lazy loading by itself should not broke it

Comment: Vue.config vs Vue.prototype ??

Answer (score 38):

a [vue3 replacement](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48895742/1149136):

```js
// Vue3

const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.config.globalProperties.$hostname = 'http://localhost:3000'


app.component('a-child-component', {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$hostname) // 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
})
```

Comment: Neat! this is nice.

Comment: As Vue 3 gets more popular, this should be higher. It's really easy compared to other solutions and less confusing if you're using Vue 3 and single-file components.

Comment: Are the globalProperties required to start with a '$'?

Answer (score 15):

I strongly recommend taking a look at [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/), it is made for globally accessible data in Vue.

If you only need a few base variables that will never be modified, I would use ES6 imports:

```
// config.js
export default {
   hostname: 'myhostname'
}

// .vue file
import config from 'config.js'

console.log(config.hostname)
```

You could also import a `json` file in the same way, which can be edited by people without code knowledge or imported into SASS.

Comment: please explain how would one import a json file

Answer (score 6):

For any Single File Component users, here is how I set up global variable(s)

1. Assuming you are using Vue-Cli's webpack template
2. Declare your variable(s) in somewhere variable.js

   ```
    const shallWeUseVuex = false;
   ```
3. Export it in variable.js

   ```
    module.exports = { shallWeUseVuex : shallWeUseVuex };
   ```
4. `Require` and assign it in your vue file

   ```
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                shallWeUseVuex: require('../../variable.js')
            };
        }
    }
   ```

Ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

Comment: Unfortunately shallWeUseVuex is a variable when defined in data(){} i.e. it can be changed.  Alas,  you can't use 'const shallWeUseVuex'  in templates or HTML, rather you have to reference the variable version from  data(){} - which is, as mentioned, not a constant.

Comment: Now that support is high, please use native modules instead of commonJS (`import` instead of `require` & `export default` instead of `module.exports = `).

Answer (score 1):

In vue cli-3 You can define the variable in main.js like

window.basurl="http://localhost:8000/";

And you can also access  this variable in any component by using 
the the 
window.basurl

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to declare the variable at the index.html because it is really global. It can be done adding a javascript method to return the value of the variable, and it will be READ ONLY.

An example of this solution can be found at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485644/1178478