# Apply global variable to Vuejs

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a javascript variable which I want to pass globally to Vue components upon instantiation thus either each registered component has it as a property or it can be accessed globally.

Note:: I need to set this global variable for vuejs as a **READ ONLY** property

Comment: for VUE-3 see the below answers.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Just [Adding Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Simple-Example)

**vue2**

For example, all components can access a global `appName`, you just write one line code:

`Vue.prototype.$appName = 'My App'`

Define that in your `app.js` file and IF you use the `$` sign be sure to use it in your template as well: `{{ $appName }}`

**vue3**

`app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios.create({ /* ... */ })`

*`$` isn't magic, it's a convention Vue uses for properties that are available to all instances.*

Alternatively, you can [write a plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) that includes all global methods or properties. See the other answers as well and find the  solution that suits best to your requirements (mixin, store, ...)

Comment: where to define it ?

Comment: but i can't get it's value inside data function. How can i do it? I've set my var like this, it read it fine at other methods, but data don't.

Comment: Important: There may be data/utilities you’d like to use in many components, but you don’t want to pollute the global scope.

Comment: When you change this at some point with `this.$appName = 'Changed'` then the other components don't notice this change. How do you change this global variable?

Comment: in v-for loop it display 'undefined'

Comment: @Frank use vuex instead for that case

Answer (score 120):

You can use a [Global Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) to affect every Vue instance. You can add data to this mixin, making a value/values available to all vue components.

To make that value Read Only, you can use the method described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript).

Here is an example:

```js
// This is a global mixin, it is applied to every vue instance. 
// Mixins must be instantiated *before* your call to new Vue(...)
Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      get globalReadOnlyProperty() {
        return "Can't change me!";
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: "<div>In Child: {{globalReadOnlyProperty}}</div>"
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function() {
    this.globalReadOnlyProperty = "This won't change it";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  In Root: {{globalReadOnlyProperty}}
  <child></child>
</div>
```

Comment: In JS code of a child component, use like this, `this.globalReadOnlyProperty`.

Comment: Wow, you really saved my bacon! I owe you bigtime! For real though this is great

Comment: Why is this available to my component in the template but not in my mounted function?  ```axios.get(API_URL + '/videos')```

Answer (score 26):

In VueJS 3 with createApp() you can use `app.config.globalProperties`

Like this:

```js
const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.foo = 'bar';

app.use(store).use(router).mount('#app');
```

and call your variable like this:

```js
app.component('child-component', {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.foo) // 'bar'
  }
})
```

> doc: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#warnhandler

If your data is reactive, you may want to use VueX.

Comment: How do I write this: `app.component('child-component', {....` in a component?

Answer (score 6):

You can use mixin and change var in something like this.

```js
// This is a global mixin, it is applied to every vue instance
Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      globalVar:'global'
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: "<div>In Child: {{globalVar}}</div>"
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function() {
    this.globalVar = "It's will change global var";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  In Root: {{globalVar}}
  <child></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, it doesnt change

Comment: @harmoniuscool it wouldn't change because for every component the data is created anew, that's why `data:` is a function. So the above example by @amin provides a copy of the global value, and nor does his example demonstrate that it could be changed. If you want mutable global variables and state, then you should use Vuex really.

Answer (score 2):

If the global variable should not be written to by anything, including Vuejs, you can use `Object.freeze` to freeze your object. Adding it to Vue's viewmodel won't unfreeze it.
Another option is to provide Vuejs with a frozen copy of the object, if the object is intended to be written globally but just not by Vue: `var frozenCopy = Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, globalObject))`

Answer (score 2):

you can use Vuex to handle all your global data

Answer (score 2):

In your main.js file, you have to import Vue like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Then you have to declare your global variable in the main.js file like this :

```
Vue.prototype.$actionButton = 'Not Approved'
```

If you want to change the value of the global variable from another component, you can do it like this :

```
Vue.prototype.$actionButton = 'approved'
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example

Answer (score 2):

If you’d like to use a variable in many components, but you don’t want to pollute the global scope. In these cases, you can make them available to each `Vue instance` by defining them on the `Vue prototype`:

```
Vue.prototype.$yourVariable = 'Your Variable'
```

Please remember to add this line before creating your `Vue instance` in your project entry point, most of time it's `main.js`

Now `$yourVariable` is available on all `Vue instances`, even before creation. If we run:

```
new Vue({
  beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log(this.$yourVariable)
  }
})
```

Then `"Your Variable"` will be logged to the console!

> doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example

If you want to make this variable immutable, you can use the static method `Object.defineProperty()`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$yourVariable', {
  get() {
    return "Your immutable variable"
  }
})
```

This method by default will prevent your variable from being removed or replaced from the `Vue prototype`

If you want to take it a step further, let's say your variable is an object, and you don't want any changes applied to your object, you can use `Object.freeze()`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$yourVariable', {
  get() {
    return Object.freeze(yourGlobalImmutableObject)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to declare the variable at the index.html because it is really global. It can be done adding a javascript method to return the value of the variable, and it will be READ ONLY. I did like that:

Supposing that I have 2 global variables (var1 and var2). Just add to the index.html header this code:

```
  <script>
      function getVar1() {
          return 123;
      }
      function getVar2() {
          return 456;
      }
      function getGlobal(varName) {
          switch (varName) {
              case 'var1': return 123;
              case 'var2': return 456;
              // ...
              default: return 'unknown'
          }
      }
  </script>
```

It's possible to do a method for each variable or use one single method with a parameter.

This solution works between different vuejs mixins, it a really global value.

Answer (score 0):

in main.js (or any other js file)

`export const variale ='someting'` 
in app.vue (or any other component)

`import {key} from '../main.js' (file location)`
define the key to a variable in data method and use it.

Comment: This does not make it a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define it in vite configuration

```
export default defineConfig({
    root:'/var/www/html/a1.biz/admin',  
    define: {
       appSubURL: JSON.stringify('/admin')
    }, ..../// your other configurations 
});
```

Now appSubURL will be accessible everywhere