# Vue JS console log without define a method

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

If I need to test an element and see what's happening at console. I'm defining a method and call it in a template like this.

```html
<template>
  <button @click="logHello()"> My Button </button>
</template>

<script>
  methods: {
    logHello(){
      console.log('Hello world')
    }
  }
</script>
```

But I don't want to define a method at each time I need to log something. Is there is a way to log something just using template and not writing anything in an instance like this:

```html
<button @click="console.log('Hello')"> My Button </button>
```

I know this one is not working but I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: You could try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40896261/3233827

Answer (score -1):

in your template use two curly braces like this 
{{console.log('hello')}}

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple, but not very recommended.
To issue a console.log directly in the template you can use:

```
this.console.log('test')
```

For example:

```
<button @click="this.console.log('Hello')"> My Button </button>
```

I hope I helped in some way

Comment: That doesn't work: `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'console')"`