# Make a variable available to all Vue components without explicitly passing it by props?

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I have a question, so in react we have react consumer and provider, that let pass variables wherever i want.
Does Vue has something like that? 
I need pass my Firebase class to almost every component, so pass it through props is a bad idea.

Comment: Use global variable  like vuex or vuestash

Comment: Have a look at [vuefire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/tree/master/packages/vuefire)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896261/apply-global-variable-to-vuejs

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper plugin for any module (ie. firebase in this case).

> /plugins/firebase-wrapper.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const FirebaseWrapper = {
  install (Vue) {
    // INSTALL
    if (this.installed) return
    this.installed = true

    // CONFIG
    const config = {
     apiKey: "",
     authDomain: "",
     databaseURL: "",
     projectId: "",
     storageBucket: "",
     messagingSenderId: ""
    }

    // INIT
    firebase.initializeApp(config)

    Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase
    Vue.firebase = firebase
  }
}

export default FirebaseWrapper
```

> main.js

```
import FirebaseWrapper from "./plugins/firebase-wrapper.js"
Vue.use(FirebaseWrapper)
```

Access firebase APIs from a .vue file like below

```
let currentUser = await this.$firebase.auth().currentUser
```

Or

```
import Vue from 'vue'
let currentUser = await Vue.firebase.auth().currentUser
```

***vuefire*** (npm module) possibly will do the same for you, ie. will create a wrapper plugin & will make firebase APIs globally available, so you won't have to write your own custom plugin.