# Reuse a js file for all vue components without importing in each

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a js file named `Constant.js` which contains all API names.

```
//Constant.js
export default {
    api1: 'api1',
    api2: 'api2',
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

How do I use this file without importing it in every Vue components there are in my app?

Comment: Add your `constant` object to the window object and use it everywhere

Comment: Just found a likely duplicate: [What is the best way to declare global variable in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367588/what-is-the-best-way-to-declare-global-variable-in-vue-js), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367588/what-is-the-best-way-to-declare-global-variable-in-vue-js/48895742#48895742) which is essentially what I wrote below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding the data directly to your `Window` object is definitely an option, the most "Vueish" way to do this is to import your data object in `main.js` (or equivalent) and [create an *instance property*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) by adding it to the Vue prototype:

**main.js**

```js
import global_constants from `./Constants`;

... // Other imports, Vue.use, Vue.component, etc.

Vue.prototype.$global_constants = global_constants; // Adds object to Vue's prototype

new Vue({
... // Create Vue instance with desired config etc.
});
```

This will make that data accessible by all child components attached to that instance through `this.$global_constants`.

The name itself is arbitrary and can be anything you'd like, and the `$` at the start is [Vue's naming convention](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#The-Importance-of-Scoping-Instance-Properties) for all instance properties.